# Listing and uploading blobs simultanously

Tags: .net, azure

I list all blobs from azure container. I have many blobs, so listing needs around 50 minutes. I need to know if in this time someone will upload a new file, it will be listed also in current listing? Or I should start new listing with new BlobContinuationToken?

```
BlobContinuationToken ct = null;
var blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();
do
{
   var blobsSegment = await blobDirectory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(true,
                            BlobListingDetails.Metadata,
                            5000,
                            ct,
                            null, 
                            null);

    foreach (var blob in blobsSegment.Results.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>())
    {
      blobs.Add(blob);
    }

    ct = blobsSegment.ContinuationToken;
}
while (ct != null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know if in this time someone will upload a new file, it will
>   be listed also in current listing?

Simple answer to your question is that it depends.

Basically when the blobs are listed, they are listed alphabetically. So if we assume that all the blobs in a blob container start with alphabet (a - z) and when you list the blobs, first all blobs starting with letter a will be returned followed by blobs starting with letter b and so on and so forth.

Now if you have started listing the blobs and you have reached till blobs starting with letter `h` and someone adds a blob starting with letter `n`, then that blob will be returned in blob listing.

However if someone adds a blob starting with letter `a`, then that blob will not be returned in blob listing. To include this blob in the blob listing you will have to restart the listing process.

Comment: Hi Mantri, could you please let me know how to restart the listing process? Thank you.